# How do I combine a variable and a text string in batch?

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

```bat
@echo off
set /a hlo=Hello
:start
echo %hlo%
pause
set /a hlo=%hlo% + World
goto start
pause
```

I want to make `hlo` become "HelloWorld".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `/a`

```
set "hlo=Hello"
set "hlo=%hlo% World"
```

Because `set /a` is for doing arithmetics and not for string operations

```
set /?
...
Two new switches have been added to the SET command:

    SET /A expression
    SET /P variable=[promptString]

The /A switch specifies that the string to the right of the equal sign
is a numerical expression that is evaluated.  The expression evaluator
is pretty simple and supports the following operations, in decreasing
order of precedence:
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! (a pretty noob quesiton, but its so hard to remember all of them) ;)